# Xamarin Forms Android apk manual install

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Environment:
Windows 10;
Visual Studio 2017

I have created my first ever extremely simple Xamarin Forms application.  I followed the deployment and publish documentation word for word, created a keystore, built the release version, created the archive as myapp.apk.

The intention for now, is to be able to manually install this apk on my android phone device.  If I don't do Linking, Proguard and obfuscation, and simply build and create the .apk file, I can install it on my phone and it seems to work fine; but the file size is about 50mb.

If I choose Proguard by check marking in the build options, when I build, I get an error saying it failed due to the space in my default windows 10 installation folder "Program Files". I tried creating a symbolic link to this directory removing the space. That did not seem to help. Still the same error. I am not sure if I did everything as I am supposed to.

Anyway, my second issue is, if I use Linking with the option "Sdk and User assemblies" and do not use either Proguard (because I can't for the reason I mentioned) or obfuscation (that also does not work and throws an error), the apk is created I can also install it on my phone; the file size is only 15mb.  But when I launch the app, it tells me "unfortunately myapp has stopped".  No other information. I have no clue what is wrong.

Comment: Use `adb logcat` in your terminal to see the logs of your Android device, that should give you a clue why the app stopped. PS: try to use paragraphs in your question, that reads a lot easier.

Comment: @Tim : Thanks for a quick reply.  Sorry for the long single paragraph.  Anyway, ignore my ignorance when I ask this.  adb commands are for debugging, right?  When I debug my app on my device from Visual Studio when it is connected to my computer, everything is fine.  No error.  Error only happens when create the apk and install it on my device and run it from the device.  does your suggestion still work in this scenario? Since there is no debug information in release version, how would I know what the problem is?

Comment: `adb logcat` gives you the complete logcat logging of your device of all your apps, regardless of debugging. Reasons for a crash are often visible there.